# CRM2011 - SDK 5.0.3 - Linq to CRM Entities Problem

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using crmsvcutil to generate early bound types. In the crm 4.0 days one was able to load related entites just by hitting the entity.ChildEntities property.

```
  //Winvs.Next.Entities.CrmDataContext dc = new Entities.CrmDataContext(new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext(
  var cred = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials();
  cred.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  //      
  using (var organizationServiceProxy = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CrmConnection"].ConnectionString), null, cred, null))
  using (Winvs.Next.Entities.CrmDataContext dc = new Entities.CrmDataContext(organizationServiceProxy))
  {
    // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
    organizationServiceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesBehavior());
    //
    foreach (var a in dc.AccountSet)
    {
      foreach (var c in a.contact_customer_accounts)
      {
        c.FullName.ToString();
      }
    }       
  }
```

When I do this with the latest CRM 2011 SDK version instead of loading realted entities I'm getting a NullReferenceException which gives me no further information about the issue.

```
foreach (var c in a.contact_customer_accounts)
```

What Do i miss? How can I load related entities with CRM2011 Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really have no clue why this is the way it is but it turned out after some researching sessions that one has to use the xrm provided code customization assembly to generate the entity object model classes.

There is a SDK Version 5.0.4 sample provided which builds a sample console showing off how to generate and consume the entity classes in a way we're all used from the CRM 4.0 xrm days.

To make a long story short I post the crmsvcutil call here, for further information you should consult the sdk sample *Walkthrough: Build a Console Application That Connects to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Using* Developer Extensions http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695803.aspx

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration" /out:Xrm\Xrm.cs /url:http://Crm/Contoso/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /domain:CONTOSO /username:administrator /password:pass@word1 /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

Answer (score 10):

I was having exactly the same issue as you. I saw those properties and was perplexed as to why they always returned `null`. They clearly were *intended* to retrieve entities for a particular relationship, yet they seemed to be "dormant."

It occurred to me that maybe the context object was not configured properly to lazy-load these "navigation" properties (to borrow a term from Entity Framework). So I started researching what I could about [`OrganizationServiceContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg308389.aspx), and found this bit about its [`LoadProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg307150.aspx) method:

> If the property represents an association, link or deferred property, calling this method provides the client a way to lazily load related resources.

That sounded like what I needed, and one of the overloads takes an `Entity` and a `Relationship` as input. So, once you have an instance of an entity with one or more relationships, you need to ask the context to load the corresponding properties. Keep in mind, the entity must be attached to the context, either automatically (because you retrieved the entity via a [context query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.createquery.aspx)), or manually using the [`Attach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.attach.aspx) method.

I'm a little confused by your code because you're using a `CrmDataContext` object rather than an `OrganizationServiceContext` object. The code samples in the 2011 SDK use the latter, and the crmsvcutil will even generate a custom instance of `OrganizationServiceContext` with methods in the form of "[ENTITY_NAME]Set" (i.e. `AccountSet` as in your example). You may need to switch over to the newer context type.

So, using your example and assuming `dc` is now an instance of `OrganizationServiceContext`, it would look like:

```
Relationship contactRel = new Relationship("contact_customer_accounts");
foreach (var a in dc.AccountSet) {

    dc.LoadProperty(a, contactRel); // Tell context to load entities from this relationship

    foreach (var c in a.contact_customer_accounts) {
        c.FullName.ToString();
    }

}
```

It is a pain to have to manually load each relationship, but I can find no other way of activating those properties.

---

**Note:** To get crmsvcutil to generate a custom `OrganizationServiceContext`, specify the  **serviceContextName** switch:

```
crmsvcutil.exe /url:<your_crm_url> /out:Xrm.cs /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

This would create a derived class named `XrmServiceContext` with accessors for all of the different entity types in your organization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I found the answer to our problem by using the latest SDK 5.0.4 Version which brings more help and a working sample about the xrm entity class topic. It feels like the first SDK releases were not ready and finished for XRM related things like entity classes.